# Вынос части javascript кода в другой файл

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Можно ли часть JS кода вынести из файла и подключать при работе основного кода? Просто там много похожих файлов с описанием переменных и в общем коде они мешают. А если их разнести в 2 разных кода и подключать в html, то они не работают. Нужно чтобы переменные были в теле функции основного JS кода. Значит добавлять их нужно именно туда.

```js
function initialize() {

  var mapProp = {
    center: {
      lat: -25.363,
      lng: 131.044
    },
    zoom: 8,
    markers: []
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
  var pos1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: -25.363,
      lng: 131.044
    },
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png',
    map: map,
    category: 'blue',
  });
  map.markers.push(pos1);

  var pos2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: -25.664,
      lng: 131.044
    },
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
    map: map,
    category: 'green',
  });
  map.markers.push(pos2);
  }
```

Comment: добавьте в вопрос пример кода, который вы бы хотели вынести в отдельный файл.

Comment: Для всяческого рода изысков есть localStorage

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, добавил

Comment: @ilya1099 - полезно было бы указать, какой код имеется в виду

Comment: @Igor, как раз эти метки нужно вынести, основной код не добавлял. Он в отдельной функции. от var pos1 = new google.maps.Marker примерно

Comment: @ilya1099 метки? Ваша функция создает карту и два маркера. Разбейте функцию на две, поместите одну из них (или обе) во внешний js файл (или файлы) и вызывайте, где это нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// File 1
function initialize() {
  var map = CreateMap();
  CreateMarkers(map);
}

// File 2
function CreateMap() {

  var mapProp = {
    center: {
      lat: -25.363,
      lng: 131.044
    },
    zoom: 8,
    markers: []
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

  return map;
}

// File 3
function CreateMarkers(map) {
  var pos1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: -25.363,
      lng: 131.044
    },
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png',
    map: map,
    category: 'blue',
  });
  map.markers.push(pos1);

  var pos2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: -25.664,
      lng: 131.044
    },
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
    map: map,
    category: 'green',
  });
  map.markers.push(pos2);
}
```